# C# - Why are DateTime.MinValue and MaxValue not compile-time constants?

Tags: c#, datetime, compile-time-constant

I wanted to have an optional date parameter for a method (defaulted to MinValue), in order to check if the user had actually supplied a value or not (supplying MinValue was invalid), but I'm not allowed as apparently it's not a compile-time constant.

According to [the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx), "The value of this constant is equivalent to 00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001."

So why is that not compile-time constant? And why is it different from passing in Int32.MinValue, which is allowed?

Comment: @Downvoter Why the downvote? I felt the question was clear, had a precise answer and was relevant to the site.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot define a DateTime constant (or structs). From MSDN allowed types for const are:

> One of the types: byte, char, short, int, long, float, double, decimal, bool, string, an enum type, or a reference type.

Comment: @jazmatician DateTime _is_ a value type. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I knew that was wrong when I typed it, but couldn't put my finger on it. :)

Answer (score 20):

Workaround: Use a nullable as parameter. IMO this is cleaner anyways since the special value is clearly different and not just a normal value.

```
void A(DateTime? p=null)
{
}
```

Another alternative is:

```
void A(DateTime p=default(DateTime))
{
}
```

Which shows that a default parameter can use `default(T)` as valid default parameter value for user defined types.

Or just overload the method for the different number of parameters.

Comment: this answers my implied question of 'how can I do what I'm trying to do?', thanks :)

Comment: You could try using [`readonly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acdd6hb7(v=vs.71).aspx) if you're looking to ensure that the value doesn't change. And I believe this can be used in conjunction with nullable type [`?`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: @eternalmatt I don't follow - how does this help having an optional DateTime parameter? If it's optional it'll need a default value, and since I can't provide a compile-time constant it seems CodeInChaos' solution is best.